# Z-index with before pseudo-element

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

I've created a 'header' element with a before-pseudo element. the pseudeo element must be behind the parent element.
Everything works great till the moment I give my 'header' a z-index.

What I want: The yellow 'header' on the foreground, the red pseudo-element in the background and a simple z-index of 30 on the yellow 'header' element.

```
header { 
    background: yellow;
    position:relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index:30; /*This is the problem*/
}

header::before { 
    content:"Hide you behind!";
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

You can test my problem on this link (http://jsfiddle.net/tZKDy/) and you see the problem when you set/remove the z-index on de 'header' element.

Comment: "What I want: The yellow 'header' on the foreground, the red pseudo-element in the background and a simple z-index of 30 on the yellow 'header' element." ... "Everything works great till the moment I give 'my header" a z-index"   it sounds like what you want occurs when the z-index is applied. what's wrong with the z-index being applied?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The ::before pseudo-element is placed inside the header element.

[CSS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content):

> The :before and :after pseudo-elements interact with other boxes as if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element.

Setting the z-index for the header element [creates a new Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context), so the new pseudo element you created can not float behind the header element, because it would have to go outside that Stacking Context.

I suggest that you simply precede the header element by another element, so it stacks correctly by default. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tZKDy/25/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Example is broken: the CSS is missing a closing brace in the first rule. I [forked and fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/dland/xs2b68ub/2/) it.

Comment: I think this is not a good solution because I can't see the point in using a relative-absolute positioning, while in fact they are not positioned relatively. Adding a `left:50px` for instance breaks it.

Answer (score 2):

I used z-index:-1 ([enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp))

```
a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Your answer looks like its using a CSS Preprocessor, presumably SCSS, but the original question only makes use of CSS. Could you clarify in your answer or format it as CSS?

Comment: This works only in relation to the nodes inside the target element ( e.g. the text ). The before element will still always overlap the background of the target element (so you can't overlay the before element with a gradient in the background-image for example).