# CSS lifted corners for child DIVs

Tags: css

I was able to make the lifted corners for a DIV using CSS. Here is the jsfiddle link 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeewanaryal/rSjXT/)

I need to design lots of child DIVs that also have lifted corners just like the parent. How can I make this?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you want to get your code to the point where simone's answer would work. It might take a bit of work to get to that point, though!

Your first problem stems from the fact that your `drop-shadow` and `lifted` classes aren't independent. You need to have a (modified) `drop-shadow` class appended to any `div` that you want the shadows to appear on, as you can see [in this ugly JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rSjXT/43/).

However, I had to make a modification to your `drop-shadow` class. What I did was get rid of the 'z-index' value on the `drop-shadow:before, drop-shadow:after` selectors, which was hiding the drop-shadow on the child `div`.

From this, we can see the first edit we need to make. You need to add

```
.lifted:after,
.lifted:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
}
```

which is necessary to make the shadows visible (remember, the `before` and `after` pseudoelements won't display if you don't set the `content`). But this isn't sufficient. The reason is because your `absolute` positioning is placing the two shadows on top of one another.

[Go to this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63Xsd/) and add/remove the `lifted` class from the child `div` to see what I mean.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rSjXT/80/) almost fixes it, but you should see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822078/z-index-with-before-pseudo-element) to see why it doesn't! You should be able to use that to fix your problem.

Comment: Hi jmeas, thanks for the answer and the fiddle code. I am trying to fix my requirements but still can not get it. I will also take a look on your solution of this answer. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Again, to explicitly state the solution, you'll need to use non-semantic code to stack elements (`div`s, presumably), because `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements are placed *inside* their parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `.lifted` class in your jsFiddle. You can use that same class in every other `div` you want.

Comment: can you please edit the fiddle and write me the code. I tried yours, I did not work.

Comment: But it does not show the lifted corner's shadow for the "child-one" div. I need the "lifted corner shadow" in every child I created inside the parent DIV of class "drop-shadow lifted"