# Use the ::before generated content selector on an iframe element

Tags: css, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#test iframe {
 border: none;
 background: #333;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#test iframe:before {
 display: block;
 content: " test";
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 background: url('overlay.png') no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 999;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="test">
  <p><iframe></iframe></p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to place an image over an `iframe` but for some reason the `::before` selector isn't getting along with the `iframe` — try replacing the `iframe` with any other element and it works. I need the `iframe` to be a child of the p element.

Comment: The content of the `iframe` is a separate web-page; I don't think you can apply CSS from the parent. If you're able, you could use `body::before {/*...*/}` in the contained page, maybe?

Comment: but im not trying to place an overlay on the content of the iframe — im trying to overlay on the iframe object itself which is why i don't think it would really matter

Comment: Any reason why you have to use the iframe:before and not just it's parent paragraph ?

Comment: because i'm going to be dealing with multiple paragraphs within the 'test' div and i only want to apply the overlay on the iframe — my reason for using the before selector to do this is because im loading additional styles on a 'permalink page' that will override the previous styles

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain on this, but I'm thinking this won't display unless the user's browser doesn't  support iFrames.

If you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7822914/1727181), it suggests that the :before and :after pseudoelements are placed inside the parent element, which in this case is the iFrame.

Now we head over to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe) and can infer the behavior of iFrame children from this code:

```
<iframe src="page.html" width="300" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Which is to say, they only display when the `src` of the iFrame isn't displayed. Again, this is just inference, but it seems like a plausible explanation.