# PHP / Wordpress preg_match

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match

Ive got the following function wrapping all iframe's in a div class="video-container"

I want to target only iframes that contain a src beginning with src="www.youtube

Is there a way to modify this function do be more specific?

Thanks in advance.

```
function div_wrapper($content) {
// match any iframes
$pattern = '~<iframe.*</iframe>~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    // wrap matched iframe with div
    $wrappedframe = '<div class="video-container">' . $match . '</div>';

    //replace original iframe with new in content
    $content = str_replace($match, $wrappedframe, $content);
}

return $content;    
}
add_filter('the_content', 'div_wrapper');
```

Comment: `if (!condition) continue;` inside the foreach as the first line. Make condition the target condition (src begins with whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a lazy match (`*?`), and check if the string that you're looking for is present in it:

```
// match any iframes
$pattern = '~<iframe.*?</iframe>~';
$content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){

  if(strpos($matches[0], 'youtube') !== false) 
    return '<div class="video-container">' . $matches[0] . '</div>';

  return $matches[0];

}, $content);
```

Needless to say this will fail in many cases. If you want something reliable use an XML parser (see [`DomDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) and [`DomElement::getAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php).

You can also try to style your iframe with pseudo-selectors like `:before` or `:after`. That way you don't need a wrapper element (eg. `iframe[src~=youtube]:after`)

Comment: Ah yes, I didnt think of using pseudo's to wrap the iframe. Ill give them a go.

Comment: the :before pseudo element won't work according to my tests and this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/13056674/1385827

Comment: The php youve supplied above works. Im not sure why you say it will fail in many cases? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is generally not a good idea, because there will always be some string combination that your expression may not match. Indeed :before doesn't seem to work with iframes, so that leaves you with the other two options :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the `$pattern` variable. Try with:

```
$pattern = '~<iframe.*src*=\'.*(http\:?)*\/\/*(www\.?)*youtube\..*</iframe>~';
```

**Note:** As @alex pointed, you are missing the protocol, so it should be `http://youtube.`, `//youtube.` or `http://www.youtube.`

Comment: It shouldn't work as missing the protocol will mean the `iframe` won't work.

Comment: @alex: thanks for point that, I forgotten because is not in the question... updated

Comment: I don't think you want it in a character class. If it's optional, use parenthesis to wrap it.

Comment: @alex: like this? `(http\:?)`