# :before/:after pseudo-elements do not transform with parent

Tags: css, css-transforms

In this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xXePd/17/) I have a div which rotates on hover and I want to know if it's possible to use :before or :after to act as a shadow. In the example the :before element gets transformed with the div and comes on top even though it has a negative z-index. I would like it to rest behind without any transformation.

It is all about css, the html is just two div, one container for perspective and the 'card' being transformed.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="card"></div>
</div>
```

About compatibility, This is a webkit only experiment I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Paging BoltClock ... http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [Z-index with before pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822078/z-index-with-before-pseudo-element)

:before and :after pseudo-elements are by definition **inside** the associated element, so it's impossible to place them outside (behind) the associated element.

You will have to go with a second element (like a `<div id="shadow">`) inserted before your `<div id="card">`.