# CSS issue with z-index on ::before when animate

Tags: css, animation, z-index, pseudo-element

Do you know why z-index is not working on ::before when I animate the parent ?

Here you can find what I mean : http://jsfiddle.net/8x3Wa/6/

```
.object {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: scale 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: scale 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.object::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822078/z-index-with-before-pseudo-element

Comment: I cant believe you found this bug on the browser. hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element created using `:before` is a child of the `.object`; hence you cannot move it behind its parent.  Instead, use `:before` and `:after` to create two elements within the `.object` and then overlap the two as you see fit.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8x3Wa/7/.

HTML:

```
<div class="object"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.object {
   position: relative;

   -webkit-animation: scale 1s infinite ease-in-out;
   animation: scale 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.object::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 20px solid red;
    z-index: 1;
}

.object::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 10px solid blue;  
    z-index: -1;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}


@keyframes scale {
  0%   { transform: scale(1, 1); }
  50%  { transform: scale(.5, .5); }
  100% { transform: scale(1, 1); }}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1); }
  50%  { -webkit-transform: scale(.5, .5); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1); }
}
```