# CSS :before is appearing :after

Tags: html, css

I have a box I want to show, and I want a background to appear behind the box to cover what remains on the screen.  The Box and the Background are bot position fixed, and the z-index for each is set as you might expect, but the background always covers the box ?

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 10px solid green;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .box:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  background-color: tomato;
  z-index: -1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Hi there, this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/is-it-possible-to-set-the-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-their-parent-e

Comment: Hello, that's the expected behaviour, please read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822078/z-index-with-before-pseudo-element

Comment: Why is the before, "additional" content, much bigger than the box? Seems a misuse of before to me. Before/after are for supplementary content.

Comment: Check this out: https://bitsofco.de/how-z-index-works/
The section: _3. Elements cannot be stacked above (or below) the parent element’s stacking level_

Answer (score 2):

You are using `position:fixed`, and then placing your `:before` at 150px from the top and 150px from the left, so it is normal that it is 'after' your `.box` that is 100px wide and 100px tall and positioned 100px from the left and 100px from the top, also in position fixed.

If you use `position:absolute` on your `:after` instead, it will be positioned relative to it's parent div.  For example:

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 10px solid green;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  left: -110px;
  background-color: tomato;
  z-index: -1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**Edit:** After getting the comment from Amaury Hanser, I'm adding a second snippet (since I don't know if it was the original poster that upvoted).

To place the `:before` "below" the `.box`, in terms of `z-index`, you could make use of the `:before` in conjunction with `:after`:

```css
.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 10px solid green;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  background-color: tomato;
  z-index: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

In simple terms, think of pseudo-elements much like child/parent elements.  A child element cannot have a z-index lower than the parent element unless the parent element has no z-index assigned.  Also, some `position` CSS rules give a "default" z-index, and no child can "break out" of it to go behind.

Comment: I think that he wants the :before element to be *behind* the main element. Nothing to do with left and top. That's why he was talking about z-index.